# Trouble getting a value from <a> link - PHP

Tags: php, get, href

My problem is that I need to save a value from the  link as a variable which will then do something. Below is my main code for this problem.

```
<table>
     <? foreach ($csv as $row) : ?>
     <tr>
      <td><a href="?GoToProfile"><? echo $row[0]; ?></a></td> 
     </tr>
     <? endforeach; ?>
   </table>
```

Basically, it prints the first column from my array $csv. However I want to save the '$row[0]' for each link - depending on which one is clicked.

This happens here:

```
     <?php
       if (isset($_GET['GoToProfile'])) {

}
?>
```

This works. E.g. when something is clicked it prints something. But I cannot find a way to save the values from each link. Depending on which one is clicked. I have tried many different methods online, but none seem to work.

I have even tried:

```
<a href="?GoToProfile?id=<?php $row[0]; ?>"><? echo $row[0]; ?></a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an ampersand (**&**) instead of a question mark

```
 <a href="?GoToProfile&id=<?php $row[0]; ?>"><? echo $row[0]; ?></a>
```

The **?** indicates the beginning of the query string, which is the data sent on a **GET** request.  In most cases it is a collection of name/value pairs, separated with **&** s.

A simple example of a GET request

> http://example.com?first=1&second=fifty

You would get the value of the parameters in PHP with $_GET

```
$first = $_GET['first'];
$second = $_GET['second'];
```

To see what the server is receiving, you can use **var_dump**

```
var_dump($_GET)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked great! I only had to add an echo to the first $row[0], but that was my fault typing it in the question. :)
Then i just had to get it with:
$Profile = $_GET['id'];

Thanks a heap! So I was on the right track? What is the difference between & and ? 
Much appreciated.

Comment: ? Is used for only first get parameter, while the next get parameter must be joined by &